# Track the Response of all the Attendees of a Meeting Request in Gmail and Outlook

Tags: .net, icalendar

I have a requirement in which I need to create and send a meeting invite on Gmail and Outlook from MVC.Net code and track their respective responses in my System.
I have been able to create and send .ics file to the mails but I am unable to track and save their RSVP responses.
Is it possible to call a Web API Request on the click of RSVP buttons to hit a URI and how can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to write a script to actually run Outlook to grab those responses. I have experience with VB.Net code handling of Excel, and there were cases where we could not get the data we wanted without running a script. This sounds like one of those cases but for Outlook.

PS (the system wont let me write a comment or I would have made this a comment first)